# How to customize transmission grating in pst-optexp?

Tags: pstricks, pst-optexp

My current working example:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](2, 2)
    \pnodes(0,1){A}
    \pnodes(2,1){B}
    \pnodes(1,1){C}
    \begin{optexp}
    \transmissiongrating[angle=180,gratingcount=10,gratingwidth=0.8,gratingheight=0.07,gratingdepth=0.03,gratingtype=binary](A)(C)(B)
    \optbox[abspos=1.5, optboxwidth=0.1,optboxheight=0.8](A)(B)
    \addtopsstyle{Beam}{linestyle=none, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=green!70!black, beaminside=false}
    \drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.4,beamdiv=4](A){1-2}
    \end{optexp}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: my now example]

I would like to do:

- A Fresnel-lens like binary transmission grating in package `pst-optexp`. Ray-tracking is not necessary.
- Keep the beam-drawing out of this grating.

Here is a sketch for my wish:

[image: My wish]

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such special gratings aren't supported out-of-the-box. However, you can use `\optdipole` to use any kind of object as component:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](2, 2)
    \pnodes(0,1){A}
    \pnodes(2,1){B}
    \begin{optexp}
        \optdipole(A)(B){%
             \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white]
            (0.05,0.5)(-0.05,0.5)(-0.05,0.45)(0,0.45)(0,0.35)(-0.05,0.35)(-0.05,0.2)(0,0.2)(0,0.15)(-0.05,0.15)
            (-0.05,-0.15)(0,-0.15)(0,-0.2)(-0.05,-0.2)(-0.05,-0.35)(0,-0.35)(0,-0.45)(-0.05,-0.45)(-0.05,-0.5)
            (0.05,-0.5)
        }
        \optbox[abspos=1.5, optboxwidth=0.1,optboxheight=0.8](A)(B)
        \addtopsstyle{Beam}{linestyle=none, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=green!70!black, beaminside=false}
        \drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.4,beamdiv=4](A){1-2}
    \end{optexp}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need that component more often, you can define it with `\newpsobject` and parameter `optdipolecomp`:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\def\fresnelgratingcomp{%
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white]
        (0.05,0.5)(-0.05,0.5)(-0.05,0.45)(0,0.45)(0,0.35)(-0.05,0.35)(-0.05,0.2)(0,0.2)(0,0.15)(-0.05,0.15)
        (-0.05,-0.15)(0,-0.15)(0,-0.2)(-0.05,-0.2)(-0.05,-0.35)(0,-0.35)(0,-0.45)(-0.05,-0.45)(-0.05,-0.5)
        (0.05,-0.5)}
\newpsobject{fresnelgrating}{optdipole}{optdipolecomp={\fresnelgratingcomp}}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](2, 2)
    \pnodes(0,1){A}
    \pnodes(2,1){B}
    \begin{optexp}
      \fresnelgrating(A)(B)
      \optbox[abspos=1.5, optboxwidth=0.1,optboxheight=0.8](A)(B)
      \addtopsstyle{Beam}{linestyle=none, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=green!70!black, beaminside=false}
      \drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.4,beamdiv=4](A){1-2}
    \end{optexp}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One more small question: How to change the size of the new object? Follow your manual, simply writing `\fresnelgrating[optdipolesize=2 0.8](A)(B)` but does not change its size.